# Numpy arrays: multi conditional assignment

Tags: python, numpy

I have two Numpy arrays as follows:

```py
>>> x
array([[0, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [0, 3, 3]])
>>> y
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 2]])
```

Comparing `x` and `y`, I would like the comparison result to assign values based on the following conditions:

1. If `x` **and** `y` values are nonzero, assign the **lower** value
2. If `x` **or** `y` are zero, assign the non zero value
3. If `x` **and** `y` are zero, assign 0

So referring to the above example, I would like the result to be:

```
>>> result
array([[0, 3, 3],
       [3, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 2]])
```

**Note**: the array size is variable. I only took a `3 x 3` array as an example. `x` and `y` will be of the same size though.

How can I do this replacement/assignment operation using Numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in select for multi condition replacement:

```
np.select([(x!=0)&(y!=0), (x==0)!=(y==0), (x==0)&(y==0)],[np.minimum(x,y), x+y, 0])
```

output:

```
array([[0, 3, 3],
       [3, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 2]])
```

although you can translate this multi condition into single condition and use adition for last two conditions with same output:

```
np.where((x!=0)&(y!=0), np.minimum(x,y), x+y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```py
tmp = np.where(x == 0, y, x) # Rule 2 and 3
result = np.where((x != 0) & (y != 0), np.minimum(x, y), tmp) # Rule 1
```

Output in `result`:

```py
array([[0, 3, 3],
       [3, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 2]])
```